# Clear Class ( new ClassName() )

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop

Question: What is Obverse of   var animals:Pets = new Pets(); ??

Script:

```
 package {

   import flash.events.MouseEvent;

   public class Pets {

     public function Pets() {
       // constructor code
       my_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick)
     }

     private function onClick(e:MouseEvent) {
       trace(Start);
     }
   }
 }
```

Problem:
     when i call Pets class from another class ( new Pets() ); , it's run the class and the addEventListener work fine BUT:

First Time: trace result

> Start

Second Time: trace result

> Start
>     Start

Third Time: trace result

> Start
>     Start
>     Start

As well as....

Thanks a lotttt

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you have posted, perhaps the problem lies with code that you have not posted?  Actually, I see a couple of minor issues: You need a semicolon after your addEventListener line, and Start should be in quotes in your trace statement, but I don't think that is necessarily causing your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `my_btn` is an instance of a button on the stage, every time you create a new instance of `Pets` you are adding a new `MouseEvent.CLICK` event handler to the same `my_btn` instance.

There are a couple of different ways to fix this but it depends on how you want things to work. If you only want one `my_btn` instance to exist then add the `MouseEvent.CLICK` handler outside of the `Pets` class (and only add it once). If each `Pets` instance needs its own button then you need to instantiate a fresh instance of `my_btn` for each instance of `Pets` (currently it looks like you are referencing the same instance of `my_btn` across all `Pets` instances).